# Php: set textbox value, simulate a button click and read the data returned

Tags: php

I am trying to collect some data from a php site. However this particular php page has transformed $POST data(to a special timestamp data that I can't replicate) with its own function(setReport() in below code) and sent to its server.
So in order to get this data, enter a stock number in the textbox and press the button is the only way to do I guess.

Below is the snippets from the source of php site that I want to grab data from.

### http://www.gretai.org.tw/ch/stock/statistics/monthly/st42.php

```
> <form name="search" method="post" action="st42.php"> <table
> width="736" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="查詢">  
> .......    
>          <td class="search-in02">股票代碼：
> 
>           <input id="input_stock_code" name="input_stock_code"
> class="input01" size="6" maxlength="6">
> 
>             <A HREF="#" onclick="ChoiceStkCode(document.getElementById('input_stock_code'));"
> onkeypress="ChoiceStkCode(document.getElementById('input_stock_code'));"
> class="page_table-text_over">代碼查詢</A>                
> 
>             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" class="input01" value="查詢" onclick="query()" onkeypress="query()"/>       
> ........
> 
> </table>
> 
> </form>                   function query(){               
> 
>       var code = document.getElementsByName("input_stock_code")[0].value;
> 
>       var param = 'ajax=true&input_stock_code='+code;
> 
>       setReport('result_st42.php',param );        
> 
>   }
```

---

I am thinking of writing a PHP code with following steps to get the data. But I don't know how to do Step 2. Is there everyone who can help on this? Or there is another way to do it? Thanks so much!!!

1. Use curl_init to read in the site.
2. Set textbox, "input_stock_code" with a value and simulate a button click.
3. Parse the results from curl_exec().

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test this since I can't read the site - but rather than getting the page, filling in the form and getting the result you could get the result page directly by going to

```
http://www.gretai.org.tw/ch/stock/statistics/monthly/result_st42.php?ajax=true&input_stock_code=<code>
```

The timestamp business that the setReport() does is just to stop your browser from loading a cached result, so you can omit it without a problem.

**Edit:** Correction, you do need to POST the ajax and input_stock_code variables. You can do this in PHP using CURL:

```php
// Build URL complete with timestamp
$url = 'http://www.gretai.org.tw/ch/stock/statistics/monthly/result_st42.php?timestamp='.time().'156';

// POST body variables
$fields = array(
            'ajax'=>urlencode('true'),
            'input_stock_code'=>urlencode('1158')
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

// Pretend we are a browser that is looking at the site
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20120403211507 Firefox/12.0');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.gretai.org.tw/ch/stock/statistics/monthly/st42.php');

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Based on a snippet post on [this website](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl).

Comment: Hi Sir, 
Thanks for reply. I did try that, but the data just won't return. If you type 1558 in the textbox and click the button on right, you will see the data came back.  http://www.gretai.org.tw/ch/stock/statistics/monthly/st42.php
If you run with the  http://www.gretai.org.tw/ch/stock/statistics/monthly/result_st42.php?ajax=true&input_stock_code=1558

Comment: Hi Sir, 
Thanks for reply. I did try that, but the data just won't return. If you type 1558 in the textbox and click the button on right, you will see the data came back.  http://www.gretai.org.tw/ch/stock/statistics/monthly/st42.php

It has no data returned with $POST data written beforehand as below. 

http://www.gretai.org.tw/ch/stock/statistics/monthly/result_st42.php?ajax=true&input_stock_code=1558

Can you kindly test it again? I couldn't find an English version of it.